# String out of range - java

Tags: java

I want get a String like this "S**s**jA**a**sdL**l**swA**a**sdM**m**"
and print a String like this "salam"
(print characters as String that are next to a Capital)

I wrote this :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] capitalalphabet = new char[]{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = input.next();
        StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i=0 ; i < s1.length() ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < capitalalphabet.length; j++) {
                if (s1.charAt(i) == capitalalphabet[j]){
                    int k = 0 ;
                    s2.setCharAt(k , s1.charAt(i+1));
                    k++;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(s2);


    }
}
```

and i got this error :

```
    SAhfdsdEDsa
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.setCharAt(StringBuffer.java:257)
    at Temp.main(Temp.java:14)
```

Comment: Well, when `i` is `s1.length() - 1`, what do you expect `s1.charAt(i+1)` to do?

Comment: (And do you realize that in that `setChar` call, `k` will *always always always*` be 0? Why are you incrementing a variabel which is about to go out of scope?)

Comment: For specifically the exception, StringBuffer#setCharAt : Except that it contains the character ch at position index. and s2 is empty.

Comment: Instead of iterating through your array with uppercase letters, you can remove the inner for-loop and change your condition to: `Character.isUpperCase(s1.charAt(i))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It happens at this line:

```
 s2.setCharAt(k, s1.charAt(i+1));
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt(int,%20char)):

> Throws:
>   StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - if start is less than zero, or greater than the length of this object.

Since your `s2` string is empty (its length is 0), you're exceeding the bounds when you try to add to it.

Also, since your `k` variable is always initialized to zero right before the `setChatAt` method, and it's only defined inside the if-statement block, you'll always be setting at index 0, even if you could.

I'd suggest you just simply try to use `StringBuilder` instead, as well as discard the messy loop of captial letters - their ASCII code is sequential, you could simply ask if character is in range:

```
for (int i=0 ; i < s1.length()-1; i++) {
    char c = s1.charAt(i);
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        s2.append(s1.charAt(i+1));
    }
}
System.out.println(s2);
```

Note that the loop scans until the index before last, since it might access the next index (and since there's no need to check the last character - it cannot be followed by anything, capital or otherwise).

Note you could also replace the if condition with `Character.isUpperCase(c)` which is more readable and elegant.

Comment: Probably we can use `i++;` after `s2.append(s1.charAt(i+1));`.